# C Program - Need help fixing complex numbers calculator program: displaying results with pointers and passing addresses

Tags: c, pointers, double

I'm creating a calculator that adds, subtracts, and multiplies complex numbers, but I keep getting errors on my displayComplexNumber. Each time I try to compile, it says, "error: expected expression before ‘double’" or "error: too few arguments to function ‘displayComplexNumber’"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getMenuChoice();
void getComplexNumber(double* num, double* imagine);
void addComplexNumber(double num1, double imagine1, double num2, double imagine2, double* num, double* imagine);
void displayComplexNumber(double* num, double* imagine);

int main()
{
    double num1,imagine1, num2, imagine2, num, imagine;
    int choice;
    do
    {
        choice = getMenuChoice();
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1: // addition
            getComplexNumber(&num1, &imagine1);
            getComplexNumber(&num2, &imagine2);
            addComplexNumber(num1, imagine1, num2, imagine2, &num, &imagine);
            displayComplexNumber(double* num, double* imagine)
            break;
        case 0: // display
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }while (choice != 0);

    return 0;
}

int getMenuChoice()
{
    int choice;
    printf("1 - addition\n");
    printf("0 - EXIT\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    return choice;
}

void getComplexNumber(double* num, double* imagine)
{
    printf("Enter the real component\n");
    scanf("%lf", num);
    printf("Enter the imaginary component\n");
    scanf("%lf", imagine);
}

void addComplexNumber(double num1, double imagine1, double num2, double imagine2, double* num, double* imagine)
{
    *num = num1 + num2;
    *imagine = imagine1 + imagine2;
}
void displayComplexNumber(double* num, double* imagine)
{
    printf("*RESULT*\n");
    printf("%.2lf + %.2lfi\n", num, imagine);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`displayComplexNumber()` shouldn't take pointers, it should just take doubles.

```
void displayComplexNumber(double num, double imagine)
```

You need to fix this in the prototype at the beginning, and in the function definition.

Then when you call it, you don't put the parameter types. It should just be:

```
displayComplexNumber(num, imagine);
```